# React Native Build Errors in Xcode

Tags: xcode, react-native

While trying to build my React Native project in Xcode keep coming across the same build errors. There are too many errors to list, but it seems to have something to do with React. Is there any way to rewind in Xcode or address the mass errors? I installed several npm/react-native libraries and used `link` to integrate them. Any idea on how to restore order, given the warnings in the image?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was finally solved here:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14382#issuecomment-313163119

In the Terminal, navigate to the `react-native/third-party/glog` folder inside node_modules (for me, this was `cd node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.4`)
Once actively in this folder, run `../../scripts/ios-configure-glog.sh`
Glog is configured and the required config.h header file is created for Xcode to find